# If I use extract() BeautifulSoup's method in a list A, it will extract the same thing in another list B (copy of A) with different ID

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

Look at this example:

```
listA = [BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>')]
```

Then I create a copy of it:

```
listB=listA[:]
```

Ok, both lists are equal but have different ids. When I append somenting in one list, it will not append on its copy. But when I use extract() method in listB, for example, like this:

```
listB[0].i.extract()
```

It will extract the same tag in listA, which has a different id of listB.

So:

```
listA

#[<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to </a>]
```

Why does it happen and is there any solution?

**EDIT:**

After searching more about this issue, a found the deepcopy() method from copy module. So I tested it with my example and it worked fine.
In shell:

```
>>> import copy
>>> listB=copy.deepcopy(listA)
>>> listB[0].i.extract()
>>> listA
#[<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>]
```

Worked in this simple example, but in my code it's a bit different, as follow:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
resp = soup.find_all('blockquote', {'class':'postMessage'})

listA = []
for i in range(len(resp)):
    if len(resp[i].findAll('a', {'onclick':"highlightReply('19176591');"})) != 0:
        if resp[i] not in listA:
            listA.append(resp[i])
listB = copy.deepcopy(listA)
```

And when I run it, the code breakes insanely, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\request.py", line 47, in <module>
    listB=copy.deepcopy(listA)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 219, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 300, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 246, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 300, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)

... (a lot of times repeating those ones)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 246, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 164, in deepcopy
    copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: lists have different ID but you duplicate BS object and now you have two BS objects but both have the same HTML inside so you get the same result when you use expand(). Beside `[:]` doesn't make "deep" copy so you can have on both list reference to the same object BS.

Comment: @furas, searching more about that issue, I've found the deepcopy() method from copy module, but it still did not work with my original code, despite work with this example I cited here. Because my original code, the listA is inside a loop, appending tags from BS findAll. Deepcopy totally bugs when copying that list, but works fine when its outside a loop. Any tip?

Comment: I think it is not issue but you missleading something. You have listA with BS object, you duplicate this list so you get listB with BS object too. Second BS object has the same HTML inside so `extract()` gives the same tag. Or create minimal working example which has still your poblem so we could test it.

Comment: @furas, I edited my question with my real code. If you want to take a look on it, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a kludge to solve the problem.

Just did like this:

```
for i listA:
    listB.append(BeautifulSoup(str(i)))
```

It copies a totally unshared list. I don't know if there is a better solution for my case.